# Is it possible to send a "free" (not charged to recipient) text message with a service provider?

Tags: sms

We've been asked by a customer whether it is possible to send a free text message to a subscriber. They would like to know if there is a way to not charge the recipient for an inbound text message?

We work with a couple text messaging services and I don't see that as an option. My assumption is that you would need to partner with each carrier and send the message from their system in order to accomplish this.

Are there any 3rd party service providers that have this capability?

Comment: You must be in Canada where you are charged for receiving text messages. I would throw rotton eggs at anybody walking in or out of a mobile phone provider in Canada. It's the least they deserve.

Comment: No, I'm in the US, and while a large group has unlimited texting plans, we still get charges both ways if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States the recipient is responsible for delivery charges, while the sender is responsible for sending charges. In Europe the sender is responsible for both.

Using online mechanisms the sender is generally not paying anything. However with Verizon I believe in the U.S. you will be charged for sending to someone's inbox no matter how you send it.

So unfortunately to answer your question: If you are in the U.S. there is no way unless you call up the carrier directly and offer to assume the delivery charge if the recipient does not have unlimited text messaging as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is possible. You need a provider that supports Free to End User (FTEU) messages, such as mBlox. There are a few of them out there, but some do not support all carriers yet (I'm not sure if mBlox does or not, we're waiting to hear from them).

[Free mobile messaging for end user](http://www.mblox.com/products/mobile-messaging/free-to-end-user/)

Another provider and interesting project we are looking into is [Private Label SMS](http://privatelabelsms.com/) they appear to have the ability to send FTEU messages as well, in addition to other standard text messaging services.

Answer (score 0):

Not this is country and carrier specific.
In Europe the receiver of a cell phone call or SMS is never charged.
In the US I am charged for receiving on my PAYG plan but not on my monthly plan, the sender has no way of knowing what plan I am on.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send Free to End Use Text Messages.....it's not easy to come by as processes need to be in place with each carrier to enable this. In effect, the originator of the TXT MSG will bare both costs - sender/receiver. This only makes sense where you as a Vendor want to be conscious of any costs to be incurred by your consumers. As well, it can be quite effective in minimizing the number of Opt-Outs from these TXT campaigns as your users won't be discouraged by the disclaimer on the MSG "STD RATES MAY APPLY".

Comment: Could you elaborate on what allows you to do this, and what technical skills are required?

Answer (score -2):

In the UK it's standard 10p to send a message and recipient pays nothing, as it should be. We in the UK can buy a text bundle like for around £5 and this gives you cheaper texts and some providers here give you free txt messages every month anyway